# I am having trouble with this kind of exercises. I am getting again.. this error Segmentation fault (core dumped). Any suggestions?

Tags: c, function, sorting, malloc

I created a (int *)table that gets from user N elements and then with the help of swap and sort functions that i created i print out the sorted table. Code Below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void swap(int **p_a, int **p_b);
void sort(int **table, int N);

int main(void){
    // Here your code !

    int *table;
    int elements, i;

    printf("Input the number of elements to store in the array : ");
    scanf("%d", &elements);

    table = (int *)malloc(elements * sizeof(int));
    if (table == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to allocate memory...");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Input %d number of elements in the array : \n", elements);
    for (i=0; i<elements; i++)
    {
        printf("element - %d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", (table + i));
    }

    printf("\nThe elements in the array before sorting: \n");
    for (i=0; i<elements; i++)
        printf("element - %d : %d\n", i+1, *(table + i));


    sort(&table, elements);


    printf("\nThe elements in the array after sorting: \n");
    for (i=0; i<elements; i++)
        printf("element - %d : %d\n", i+1, table[i]);


    free(table);
} 

void swap(int **p_a, int **p_b)
{
    int temp;

    temp = **p_a;

    **p_a = **p_b;
    **p_b = temp;
}

void sort(int **table, int N)
{
    int i,j;
    int current_position;
    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        current_position = i; // current_position is the current element of the table
        for (j=i; j<N; j++)
        {
            /* 
                compares all the elements after the current position
                if the condition is true then the current position now is the next position, and compares it again.
                When the outer loop will loop again it means that the smallest element was found and then compares the other ones
            */
            if (*table[j] < *table[current_position]); 
                current_position = j;
        }

        swap(&table[current_position], &table[j]);
    }
}
```

Console:

```
Input the number of elements to store in the array : 5
Input 5 number of elements in the array : 
element - 1: 5
element - 2: 99
element - 3: 22
element - 4: 1
element - 5: 0

The elements in the array before sorting: 
element - 1 : 5
element - 2 : 99
element - 3 : 22
element - 4 : 1
element - 5 : 0
```

Error:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Any suggestions?Are my functions correct structured, are the functions arguments correct?. For the code inside sort i am 100% sure that is correct.

Comment: You've posted several questions like this.  Time to start learning how to use a debugger to diagnose these bugs.  Staring at the code isn't very effective, especially for a non-expert, and asking on StackOverflow every time isn't a great long-term solution.

Comment: Other tools to learn about are malloc debuggers (e.g. valgrind) or other memory sanitizers (e.g. gcc -fsanitize=address).

Comment: Also, enable compiler warnings, and/or try a compiler that gives better warnings than your current one.  gcc warns about `if (*table[j] < *table[current_position]);` in which the trailing semicolon causes it not to do what you want, and the following line executes unconditionally.  (Lesson: the part of your program that you are "100% sure is correct" is usually where the bug is. :-)

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks for the advise

Comment: Rolled back so as not to hide the evidence. This isn't where the code is that needs fixing: it's on your own machine.

Comment: @WeatherVane Did you run it on your pc?

Comment: I meant that if you edit bugs mentioned out of the question, the comments become hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You have one-too-many levels of indirection in your declarations of `sort` and `swap`. Your declarations should be:

```
void swap(int *p_a, int *p_b);
void sort(int *table, int N);
```

Your `swap` can simply be:

```
void swap(int *p_a, int *p_b)
{
    int temp;

    temp = *p_a;

    *p_a = *p_b;
    *p_b = temp;
}
```

Your `sort` looks to be a mix of a bubble and insertion sort. Pick one or the other. With slight modification, a naive bubble-sort would be:

```
void sort(int *table, int N)
{
    int i,j;

    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        for (j=i; j<N; j++)
        {
            if (table[j] < table[i])
                swap(&table[i], &table[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

After fixing the misplaced `';'` at the end of your `if` statement and changing your call to `sort(table, elements);`, you would receive:

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/sortandswap
Input the number of elements to store in the array : 5
Input 5 number of elements in the array :
element - 1: 5
element - 2: 99
element - 3: 22
element - 4: 1
element - 5: 0

The elements in the array before sorting:
element - 1 : 5
element - 2 : 99
element - 3 : 22
element - 4 : 1
element - 5 : 0

The elements in the array after sorting:
element - 1 : 0
element - 2 : 1
element - 3 : 5
element - 4 : 22
element - 5 : 99
```

In C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714). If you use the dereferenced pointer to set your *type-size*, you eliminate the chance of getting it wrong. A correct use that uses the dereferenced pointer to set the *type-size* would be:

```
table = malloc(elements * sizeof *table);
```

---

**Edit - Response To Comment**

`table` is an integer pointer in `main()` there were no changes there. The only change made to the allocation was to use the dereferenced pointer to set the *type-size* rather than `sizeof(int)`. In trivial cases, as here, there is little chance of using the wrong *type-size* (though I do see it often). The benefit comes when allocating for pointers to objects like structures that may have many members. Here:

```
int *table;
...
table = malloc(elements * sizeof *table);
```

is equivalent to:

```
table = malloc(elements * sizeof(int));
```

(where `table` is a pointer to `int`, thus `*table` is simply type `int`)

To show that `table` remains a pointer to int, the complete example would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void swap(int *p_a, int *p_b);
void sort(int *table, int N);

int main(void){
    // Here your code !

    int *table;
    int elements, i;

    printf("Input the number of elements to store in the array : ");
    scanf("%d", &elements);

    table = malloc(elements * sizeof *table);
    if (table == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to allocate memory...");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Input %d number of elements in the array : \n", elements);
    for (i=0; i<elements; i++)
    {
        printf("element - %d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", (table + i));
    }

    printf("\nThe elements in the array before sorting: \n");
    for (i=0; i<elements; i++)
        printf("element - %d : %d\n", i+1, *(table + i));


    sort(table, elements);


    printf("\nThe elements in the array after sorting: \n");
    for (i=0; i<elements; i++)
        printf("element - %d : %d\n", i+1, table[i]);


    free(table);
} 

void swap(int *p_a, int *p_b)
{
    int temp;

    temp = *p_a;

    *p_a = *p_b;
    *p_b = temp;
}

void sort(int *table, int N)
{
    int i,j;

    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        for (j=i; j<N; j++)
        {
            if (table[j] < table[i])
                swap(&table[i], &table[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

(**note:** following a failure in `main()` do not return a *negative* value to the shell. C defines two exit values to be returned to the shell, `EXIT_SUCCESS` (value is `0`), and `EXIT_FAILURE` (value is `1`))

Comment: i understand everything you comment above. The only thing is i wanted the table to be an integer pointer so i can malloc inside main, If you know what i am trying to say ? So if i would do that way in sort i have to to ** the table. Also i am a ECE student, so to allocate memory we have to use the command i wrote above, with type casting for readable code.Thanks